# JSX Curly Expression inside a Curly Expression

Tags: reactjs

I have the following sub-expression inside the main one, and it's flagged as an error. It's also an error if I remove the internal one's curly braces.

```
{!isNonParticipatingUser(props) 
&&
    <LinkContainer to="/contactUs">
        <Dropdown.Item href="#">Contact Us</Dropdown.Item>
    </LinkContainer>
    {props.appData && props.appData.appProperties
    &&
        <Dropdown.Item target="_blank" href={getAppPropertiesValue(props, 'link.employee.faq')}>FAQs
        </Dropdown.Item>
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the first thing I notice is you aren't returning a single element from your first `&&`. You'll need a fragment or wrapping `div`.

Comment: Also *flagged as an error* is really unhelpful. I'm sure you were given more detail than that?

Comment: I think @BrianThompson is correct... you can do what you want if you collect your stuff into a single parent fragment/element.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
return(
     <>
         {!isNonParticipatingUser(props) 
         &&
         <>
             <LinkContainer to="/contactUs">
               <Dropdown.Item href="#">Contact Us</Dropdown.Item>
             </LinkContainer>
         {props.appData && props.appData.appProperties
             &&   
                 <Dropdown.Item target="_blank" href= getAppPropertiesValue(props, 'link.employee.faq')}>FAQs
                 </Dropdown.Item>
         }
         </>
         }
     </>
    );
```